# DECLARE keyword simply won't work

Tags: mysql

I've got an incredibly simple statement that won't work for some reason.

I'm trying to do a FOR loop:

```
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 2;
WHILE counter < 8
....
SET counter = counter + 1;
```

Incredibly basic, yet I get an error when trying to run the `DECLARE` statement.  I tried using a user variable, which worked but then the WHILE statement wouldn't work

```
SET @counter = 2;
WHILE @counter <8
....
SET @counter = @counter + 1;
```

Is there a system variable that I may have changed that would cause this sort of behavior?  This is really frustrating, as everywhere I look indicates I'm doing it correctly.  I can literally copy paste code from other solutions and it won't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your code inside of a stored procedure? If not, you'll have to create a stored procedure to use these features.

More generally, what problem are you trying to solve? Often, the better solution in a database environment looks more like a query than like a loop.

The documentation for [`DECLARE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html) indicates it must be used between `begin...end`, and the documentation for `begin`...`end` is used inside stored procedures and functions.

Also, the syntax for [`WHILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html) statements is:

```
...
WHILE (some_condition) DO
    some_commands
END WHILE
...
```

You're missing the `DO` and `END WHILE`

Comment: (This is not incredibly simple.)

Comment: It's incredibly easy in other languages but it hasn't been in mysql for sure.  I think my logic is good, I'm basically just working with doing some joins on 2 really huge datasets so I'm using MOD to take bites out of it instead and a loop seems like the best way to split it up.

Comment: One approach would be to write your loop in another language, and use MySQL for the query portion. You could also consider running multiple queries in parallel. You may find (depending on how things are indexed, etc.) that the time to run through each of ten loops is 1/10th the overall time. The MyISAM table engine and table compression can also help with speeding up large joins.

Comment: Yea handling the logic and looping in Python was going to be my backup plan but I've got the bandwidth to mess with this and I wanted to work it out in pure MySQL.  I finally got it figured out, thanks for the help!